# calling function on while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop

I'm making a calculator program but I already encounter a problem. Well, my code is in a loop that will call a function to display the choices and then ask the user to pick, a/s/m/d are the choices. If the input is on the choices, it will proceed to the next step. Otherwise, it will loop and then call the function again.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void home()
{
    cout << "\nChoose your operation:" << endl;
    cout << "\tType [A] for Addition" << endl;
    cout << "\tType [S] for Subtraction"<< endl;
    cout << "\tType [M] for Multiplication" << endl;
    cout << "\tType [D] for Division" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    char operation;
    bool no_operator = true;
    int design = 73;

    for (int i = 0; i < design; i++){
        if (i == 25){
            cout << " WELCOME TO CALCULATOR ";
            i += 22;
        }
        else i == 72 ? cout << "*\n" : cout << "*";
    }
    while (no_operator){
        home();
        cout << "\nOperation: ";
        cin >> operation;

        if (operation == 'A' || operation == 'a')
        {
            cout << "\nIt will going to add numbers";
            no_operator = false;
        }
        else if (operation == 'S' || operation == 's')
        {
            no_operator = false;
            cout << "\nIt will going to subtract numbers";
        }
        else if (operation == 'M' || operation == 'm')
        {
            no_operator = false;
            cout << "\nIt will going to multiply numbers";
        }
        else if (operation == 'D' || operation == 'd')
        {
            no_operator = false;
            cout << "\nIt will going to divide numbers";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\tInvalid Input: You must enter A/S/M/D only\n";
            //home();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My problem is it will run the '''home()''' in else statement even if the input is correct on the second loop.

I want to stop the '''home()''' to be called when the input is correct

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to figure out which paths your program takes? Be sure to check what 'cin' puts into your 'operation' variable.

Comment: ot: That loop to print the title is really obscure, it took me some time to understnad what it does. I think it can be simplified a lot if you consider that `std::string(n,'*');` constructs a string of n-times `*`

Comment: Please don't use either `using namespace std` or `endl`.

Comment: Your loop begins with `home();` which is called unconditionally. If you call it as last statement (in the `else`), then you would call it twice in a row...

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number cool! New knowledge for me but I can't find this on the internet. What are the keywords to search for?

Comment: keywords: `cppreference std::string constructor` -> https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

Comment: @Spencer why? I don't get it

Comment: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). `

Comment: `endl` flushes the stream. Often you only want to add a `\n` but `endl` adds a new line and flushes the stream. Sometimes its what you want sometimes not.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number But usually not.  The only really good use case I can think of is prompting for user input.

Comment: You should add `if (std::iswspace(operation)) cin >> operation;` just before the big `if` statement.

Comment: @Spencer: flushing avoids some incomprehension from beginner (during debugging). performance is generally not the point there.

Comment: @Spencer and for `cout` debugging

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly fine. Make sure you're inputting the correct letters.
Also for this code, a "do while()" loop would be better.

Answer (score -1):

You program is working perfectly fine as the input is correct it does not show the home rather print the message it will going to divide etc.